# Appointment scheduling in Postgres: querying available times for appointments?

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design

I have a simple schedule table as follows:

```sql
CREATE TABLE provider_schedule(
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    provider_id uuid,

    date_from timestamptz NOT null,
    date_to timestamptz NOT null,

    created_at TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
    updated_at TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),

    FOREIGN KEY (provider_id) REFERENCES app.providers (cognito_id) ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

And I insert some availability times here ('2020-05-12T19:00:00+00:00' to '2020-05-12T23:00:00+00:00'):

```sql
insert into app.provider_schedule (provider_id, date_from, date_to) 
values 
('ffc8631f-22d6-4519-b738-793a74cab731', '2020-05-12T19:00:00+00:00','2020-05-12T23:00:00+00:00');
```

But when querying it as such, it returns no results, when the time is clearly between the schedule?

```sql
select providers.first_name, providers.last_name, provider_schedule.date_from, provider_schedule.date_to 
FROM app.provider_schedule, app.providers
where provider_schedule.provider_id = providers.cognito_id
  and provider_schedule.date_from >= '2020-05-12T21:15:00+00:00'
  and provider_schedule.date_to <= '2020-05-12T21:30:00+00:00';
```

What am I doing wrong here that is not Provider whose schedule availability clearly falls between the query window time?

Comment: If I remove the constraints on the query and query only where provider_schedule.provider_id matches providers.cognito_id, it works and returns the data. For some reason the date comparators are not working

Comment: How about using proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax?

Comment: This was from a tutorial...

Comment: @StephenALizcano . . . That is really, really, really sad.  Find a more modern tutorial.

Comment: Best I could find! There is not much when it comes to SQL + Appointment Scheduling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your condition on the range is wrong.

The column `date_from` from your example contains the hour `19:00`. But your condition requires `date_from >= 21:15` - obviously that isn't matching as `19:00` is not greater than `21:15`

You need to swap the edges:

```
SELECT pr.first_name, pr.last_name, ps.date_from, ps.date_to 
FROM app.provider_schedule ps
  JOIN app.providers pr ON ps.provider_id = pr.cognito_id
WHERE '2020-05-12T21:15:00+00:00' >= ps.date_from
  and '2020-05-12T21:30:00+00:00' <= ps.date_to;
```

Alternatively this can be done using a [timestamp range](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html):

```
SELECT pr.first_name, pr.last_name, ps.date_from, ps.date_to 
FROM app.provider_schedule ps
  JOIN app.providers pr ON ps.provider_id = pr.cognito_id
WHERE tstzrange(ps.date_from, ps.date_to) @> tstzrange('2020-05-12T21:15:00+00:00', '2020-05-12T21:30:00+00:00');
```

The `@>` operator means "does the left range contain the right range"

Comment: Thank you! Is timestamptz or timestamp better to use in these situations? Our time ranges vary across three time zones (USA), but I know timestamptz converts to UTC in the backend, so maybe just use timestamp. Viele gruße aus Frankfurt

Comment: If you need to deal with different time zones, then `timestamptz` is the only choice you have